# How to get only record ID when doing Select in surrealdb?

Tags: surrealdb

Just a simple question. the following is a SurrealQL

```sql
SELECT id FROM table;
```

the returned object has an array of objects under the result as the following

```json
[
   {id:table:reacord_id1},
   {id:table:reacord_id2},
   {id:table:reacord_id3},
   ...
]
```

What I want is only the record IDs (reacord_id1, reacord_id2, ...) and I *can* split the result set by ':' or any other string manipulation method, but I want a SurrealQL solution.

Hint: I remember there was a function called VALUE or something which does that

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
SELECT meta::id(id) FROM user
```

do what you want?

You then could use `string::split()` by `:` or maybe even call it twice,  haven't tried that

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/functions/meta

*The meta::id function extracts and returns the table id from a SurrealDB Record ID.*

```
// Query
SELECT meta::id(id) as id FROM user;

// Output
[
    {id:reacord_id1},
    {id:reacord_id2},
    {id:reacord_id3},
    ...
]
```

**Method 2**

https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/functions/string#split

*The string::split function splits a string by a given delimiter.*

```
// Query
SELECT string::split(<string>id,':')[1] as id FROM user.

// Output
[
    {id:reacord_id1},
    {id:reacord_id2},
    {id:reacord_id3},
    ...
]
```

First method is easy to use. both method will give you same output.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**